# Get the nested nodes in a string with Xpath or HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, xpath, html-agility-pack

On the server, I am getting back a HTML snippet as a string via AJAX from the client JS. The contents are a nested DIV with ul, li items. [HTML DIv snippet](http://dabblet.com/gist/b7fdb5ec69d0aee552db)

```
<div> //please see link above
        <ul class="tree" id="ulID" name="input">
            <li><span class="vertical..."></span>
                <div></span>1</div>
                <ul>..
</div>
```

I am using C# HtmlAgilityPack, but I am not able to get the nested contents to extract the data, and add data back.

Below is some of the code.

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// nested
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

bool failed = false;

// Use:  htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString); 

// ParseErrors is an ArrayList 
if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
    // Handle any parse errors as required
    // check if string was JSON formatted
    if (htmlDoc.LoadHtml(JSONdeserialize(htmlString)).ParseErrors.Count() > 0) failed = true;
}
else
{

    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ulID");

        if (bodyNode != null)
        {
            // **how can I get the contents of the node here??****
            // what is the xpath to get all the structured contents so I can walk the tree
            // If option walk tree
            // How can I build foreach(HTMLnode node in nodes) nested array
        }
    }
}
```

1. What is the Xpath to select all content in DOM string, when I don't have body, but simple [Div enclosed string](http://dabblet.com/gist/b7fdb5ec69d0aee552db).
2. How can I extract all the nodes, and their contents at their nested levels
3. Any recommendations on how to save this structure? so I can easily recover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the Xpath you have now is correct.
I am also unsure when the first ul tag ends. If it ends just before the div closes. Then you can just use this xpath.

```
"//ul[@id='ulID']"
```

Then you get the first ul htmlnode. Then you can iterate through its children.
I highly recommend you take a look at some [xpath examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: this is giving me all UL items, how can I walk this for a) all items, b) only `li` items, or only target `div` items below the list  I did this "//ul[@id='ulID']//li" but did not work for li items

Comment: After this xpath: "//ul[@id='ulID']" You have a single HtmlNode. You can call. bodyNode.ChildNodes - to get an HtmlNodeCollection of all the childnodes. In a foreach loop you can sort them out with an if expression as such if(htmlNode.OriginalName == "li").

Comment: Will this give me a dictionary like list, or how can I preserve the hierarchical nesting?